# Guardar fecha del ultimo día que se uso la web

Tags: javascript, date

Estoy tratando de guardar la ultima fecha que se accedió a mi página web, estoy realizando un new date pero siempre me guarda la ultima hora y dia actuales, no la fecha anterior o la hora anterior como se haría esto? Estoy usando la siguiente librería de cookies [API](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)
Tengo el siguiente codigo.

```js
    let dia = new Date();
    let fecha = dias.innerHTML = 'Fue el dia ' +
          dia.getDate() + "-" + (dia.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + dia.getFullYear();
    let hora = tiempo.innerHTML = 'A la hora ' + dia.getHours() + ":" + dia.getMinutes() + ":" + dia.getSeconds();
    console.log(fecha, hora);
Cookies.set("sesion", fecha,{expires:7});
Cookies.set("sesion2", hora,{expires:7});
Cookies.get('sesion');
Cookies.get('sesion2');
```

Como conseguiría que se mostrara por ejemplo si entrara esta noche a las 22 horas o tal vez mañana? Como ultima vez de entrada?

> Fue el dia 28-12-2020

> A la hora 19:23:21

En vez de

> Fue el dia 28-12-2020

> A la hora 22:00:00

Comment: Dónde estás guardando el uso anterior del sitio??

Comment: En una cookie, he añadido el enlace de la API

Comment: Si cada vez que consultas hacer primero el SET y luego el GET, siempre vas a fijar lo que creaste al principio (la fecha actual)... prueba invirtiendo el orden

Comment: sigue apareciendo la hora actual no se como comprobar esto o tal vez no me esté funcionando bien

Answer (score 1):

### Con localStorage

Utiliza localStorage para guardar el último momento de conexión.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    let date = new Date();
    let save = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if (localStorage.getItem("lastDate") == null) {
    localStorage.setItem("lastDate", save);
    save = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
    localStorage.setItem("lastHour", save);
console.log("Last date: " + localStorage.getItem("lastDate"));
console.log("Last hour: " + localStorage.getItem("lastHour"));
} else {
console.log("Last date: " + localStorage.getItem("lastDate"));
console.log("Last hour: " + localStorage.getItem("lastHour"));
}
});
```

**Refrescando las fechas**

Necesitarás eliminar los datos de localStorage y ponerlos nuevamente.

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    let date = new Date();
    let save = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if (localStorage.getItem("lastDate") == null) {
    localStorage.setItem("lastDate", save);
    save = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
    localStorage.setItem("lastHour", save);
console.log("Last date: " + localStorage.getItem("lastDate"));
console.log("Last hour: " + localStorage.getItem("lastHour"));
} else {
localStorage.removeItem("lastDate");
localStorage.removeItem("lastHour");
localStorage.setItem("lastDate", save);
    save = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
    localStorage.setItem("lastHour", save);
console.log("Last date: " + localStorage.getItem("lastDate"));
console.log("Last hour: " + localStorage.getItem("lastHour"));
}
});
```

#### Puntos a tener en cuenta

Los elementos guardados en localStorage nunca expiran (ni aunque se cierre el navegador o se apague el equipo) así que tendrás que borrarlos manualmente.

- [Referencia de localStorage en W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)
- [Referencia de localStorage en la MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

### Con cookies

```
let date = new Date();
let save = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

setCookie("lastDate", save, 2);
save = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
setCookie("lastHour", save, 2);
console.log("lastDate: "+ getCookie("lastDate"));
console.log("lastHour: "+ getCookie("lastHour"));
```

- [Referencia de cookies de javascript en W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)
- [Referencia de cookies de javascript en la MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/document.cookie)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda :), pero debería usar cookies obligatoriamente, ya que asi me lo han pedido

Answer (score 0):

Esto extrage deba cookie para esa función

```
//Día mes Año hora segundo y minutos
let fecha = new Date("d/mY | H:i:s");
setcookie("sesion", fecha, time()+604800);
```

El extenso número equivale a 7 días en segundos