# Cómo puedo mostrar la última conexión (fecha y hora) de un usuario?

Tags: javascript

Tengo por un parte:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>
            Última Conexión
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="fecha">
        </p>
        <script src="js/Pantalla2.js">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Y luego por otra parte:

```
document.cookie = "usuario = Hola Mundo; expires = Thu, 25 Nov 2021 12:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
document.getElementById( "fecha" )
.innerHTML = "La última vez que entraste fue: " + ;
```

He buscado a través de distintas fuentes pero realmente con JavaScript puro, no he encontrado la solución correcta que me ayude a solucionar el problema.

Comment: Y esa información de dónde la planeas obtener?

Comment: estas guardando datos del usuario en el backend ?

Comment: La información se obtiene a partir de que el usuario introduce su correo en un input y de ahí obtener la última conexión y mostrarla con cookies. Respecto al backend, no hay que almacenar nada, ya que se trata de un ejemplo sencillo de cookies. Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podemos hacer esto de 2 formas distintas

#### Con localStorage

Puedes guardar esto en localStorage y obtener la hora de última conexión

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
if (localStorage.getItem("lastDate") == null) {
const d = new Date().getDay()+"-"+(new Date().getMonth() + 1)+"-"+new Date().getFullYear();
localStorage.setItem("lastDate", d);
console.log("Last date: "+ localStorage.getItem("lastDate"));
} else {
console.log("Last date: "+ localStorage.getItem("lastDate"));
}
});
```

**Puntos a tener en cuenta con localStorage**

Los datos almacenados en localStorage no se borran ni porque se cierre el navegador o incluso se apague el equipo

[Referencia de localStorage en W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)

[Referencia de localStorage en la MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

#### Con cookies

```
let date = new Date();
let save = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

setCookie("lastDate", save, 2);
save = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
setCookie("lastHour", save, 2);
console.log("lastDate: "+ getCookie("lastDate"));
```

#### Puede que sea útil

- [Guardar la fecha de la última vez que se usó la web](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/417228/guardar-fecha-del-ultimo-d%C3%ADa-que-se-uso-la-web/417236#417236)
- [Referencia de cookies de javascript en W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)
- [Referencia de cookies de javascript en la MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/document.cookie)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, debido a que la solución que necesitaba, era a través de cookies, pensaba que especificaría al mostrar cookies en el trozo de código pero tú veo que lo has entendido perfectamente, que grande.

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta, tal cuál está planteada, queda muy abierta a interpretaciones o según lo que necesites según tus requisitos. Por ejemplo, algunos aspectos que pueden hacer cambiar el diseño de tu solución:

- ¿Se permiten conexiones desde diferentes dispositivos?
- ¿Consideras la fecha de conexión el momento de hacer login o logout? ¿O simplemente desde el último acceso?
- ¿Necesitas que ese dato lo guarde algún backend?

Con la información disponible, optaría por guardarlo en el LocalStorage en lugar de en una cookie. Un ejemplo sería:

```
localStorage.setItem('last-connection', Date.now());
```

Y para leer ese dato:

```
localStorage.getItem('last-connection');
```

Recuerda que `getItem(clave)` devolverá el valor previamente almacenado como una cadena, por lo que deberás tenerlo en cuenta para convertirlo al dato apropiado (en el ejemplo, sería un Date).

Espero que te sirva como orientación. Cualquier duda puedes utilizar los comentarios para aclararlas y ayudarte.

Comment: Perdón por no especificar, se trata de un ejemplo sencillo sin ningún tipo de backend, donde el usuario se obtiene al introducir el correo en un input, pero cómo solo quería la última conexión, he puesto solo un trozo de código. Con localStorage también funciona correctamente, gracias.